# Convert String File Path to IntPtr

Tags: c#, c

I'm using [Mupen64Plus](https://github.com/mupen64plus).

I'm using **C#** to talk to the `mupen64plus.dll` API which is written in **C**.

I'm trying to Load a Save State file and convert the `String` path to an `IntPtr` so the API can read it.

The problem is when I load it with Mupen's `M64CMD_STATE_LOAD` command, it gives me the error `Failed to open savestate file (null)`, which probably means the string wasn't converted right and the pointer is wrong.

---

[Mupen64Plus_v2.0_Core_Front-End](https://mupen64plus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mupen64Plus_v2.0_Core_Front-End)

**M64CMD_STATE_LOAD**

This command will attempt to load a saved state file. **If ParamPtr is not NULL, this function will load a state file from a full pathname specified by this pointer.** Otherwise (ParamPtr is NULL), it will load from the current slot.

---

**API**

I'm using this API code here [mupen64plusCoreApi.cs](https://github.com/TASVideos/BizHawk/blob/master/BizHawk.Emulation.Cores/Consoles/Nintendo/N64/NativeApi/mupen64plusCoreApi.cs)

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate m64p_error CoreDoCommandPtr(m64p_command Command, int ParamInt, IntPtr ParamPtr);
CoreDoCommandPtr m64pCoreDoCommandPtr;

private enum m64p_command
{
    M64CMD_STATE_LOAD,
    ...
}
```

**Load Save State File** (Problem)

```
// Open Select File Window
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog selectFile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
Nullable<bool> result = selectFile.ShowDialog();

if (result == true)
{
    // Convert String File Path to IntPtr
    string fileName = selectFile.FileName;

    IntPtr filePath = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(fileName);
    GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc(filePath, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    IntPtr pinnedFilePath = gch.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // API Load Save State File from Path
    m64pCoreDoCommandPtr(m64p_command.M64CMD_STATE_LOAD, 0, pinnedFilePath); // Problem here

    gch.Free();
}
```

Comment: Is `pinnedFilePath` null?

Comment: @dedecos I put a breakpoint to check, it says `m_handle {12928685} System.IntPtr`. I also tried a check `if (pinnedFilePath == null)` and it was not null. I think Mupen gives a `(null)` error if it's corrupt. If it is truly null, Mupen will automatically load the first found file from the current slot.

Comment: @dedecos This file shows where it gives the error if the file path is null. `"Failed to open savestate file %s", filepath` https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core/blob/master/src/main/savestates.c I think for it to correctly see a true null is the pointer needs to be `IntPtr.Zero` from C#, otherwise I don't know what Mupen is seeing.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you are leaking memory by not [calling `FreeHGlobal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) on `filePath`. Also, you don't need the manual pinning in the first place because you can have another version of the delegate declaration with `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]` and the last parameter declared as `string`.

Comment: Could you debug the mupen dll and check the value of `filepath` there?

Comment: @GSerg I created another delegate declaration with a string parameter and it appears to be working, thanks. I thought I was going to have to use what was already set up in code. That is a lot easier than trying to convert it.

Comment: Is there anything memory related that might be moved around by the runtime? Have you tried using the fixed statement?

Comment: @fstam I'm not experienced enough to know how unmanaged memory works. GSerg's answer was able to bypass the problem.

Comment: @GSerg I have another similar question regarding `int` to `IntPtr` conversion if you'd like to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/57550669/6806643