# Put an Int into memory and assign it to an IntPtr

Tags: c#, wpf, memory

I'm using [Mupen64Plus](https://github.com/mupen64plus).

I'm using **C#** to talk to the `mupen64plus.dll` API which is written in **C**.

---

#### API

I'm using this API code here [mupen64plusCoreApi.cs](https://github.com/TASVideos/BizHawk/blob/master/BizHawk.Emulation.Cores/Consoles/Nintendo/N64/NativeApi/mupen64plusCoreApi.cs)

---

#### API Commands

The API has a command to Mute the audio.

[Mupen64Plus v2.0 Core Front-End Wiki](https://mupen64plus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mupen64Plus_v2.0_Core_Front-End)

1. **M64CMD_CORE_STATE_SET**

   This command will set the value of a state parameter in the emulator core.

   **ParamInt:** An m64p_core_param enumerated type specifying the desired state variable.
   **ParamPtr:** *Pointer to an integer* to containing the value of the requested state variable.
2. **M64CORE_AUDIO_MUTE**

   1 if muted, otherwise 0

---

I've added a new delegate declaration so I can use the `M64CMD_CORE_STATE_SET` command.

```
public enum m64p_core_param
{
    M64CORE_AUDIO_MUTE,
    ...
};

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate m64p_error CoreDoCommandCoreStateSet(m64p_command Command, m64p_core_param ParamInt, IntPtr ParamPtr);
CoreDoCommandCoreStateSet m64pCoreDoCommandCoreStateSet;
```

Mute

```
IntPtr mute = ???

m64pCoreDoCommandCoreStateSet(
    m64p_command.M64CMD_CORE_STATE_SET, 
    m64p_core_param.M64CORE_AUDIO_MUTE,
    mute // <-- IntPtr value for mute (0)
);
```

---

#### Attempts

**1**

[Marshal.WriteIntPtr Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.writeintptr?view=netframework-4.8)

This does not seem to give a mute value of 0. I'm not sure how to correctly use it.

```
int elementSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
IntPtr unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(elementSize);

Marshal.WriteIntPtr(unmanagedArray, elementSize, ((IntPtr)(0)));

IntPtr mute = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(unmanagedArray, elementSize);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedArray);
```

**2**

[Microsoft Developer Forums - Marshal.Copy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11fae50a-21bf-4c73-b03c-0fa5fd0ee7eb/converting-double-to-intptr-and-then-to-byte-array?forum=csharpgeneral)

No errors, but API does not enable Mute.

```
// Create a managed array.
double[] managedArray = { 0 };

// Initialize unmanaged memory to hold the array.
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(managedArray[0]) * managedArray.Length;

IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

// Copy the array to unmanaged memory.
Marshal.Copy(managedArray, 0, pnt, managedArray.Length);

// Copy the unmanaged array back to another managed array.
double[] managedArray2 = new double[managedArray.Length];

Marshal.Copy(pnt, managedArray2, 0, managedArray.Length);

var value = Marshal.ReadInt32(pnt, 0);

IntPtr mute = new IntPtr(value);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
```

---

#### Questions and Problem

**ParamPtr:** *Pointer to an integer* to containing the value of the requested state variable.
Does that mean I need to put an `int` into memory, then assign it to an `IntPtr`?

I'm not able to use a regular `int` or `ref int` for the mute value, it causes the program to go haywire or crash for trying to access protected memory, it's trying to access that `int` place in the memory. The window goes black, or changes sizes, or speeds up.

How can I put a value of 0 or 1 into memory, then assign that position to an IntPtr to use for the mute value?

Comment: @mjwills I will update the question with an example.

Comment: `Does that mean I need to put an int into memory, then assign it to an IntPtr?` - no, that means you need to have another overload of the delegate, with the last parameter being `ref int`. `I'm not able to use a regular int or ref int for the mute value, it causes the program to go haywire` - please show you do that.

Comment: @GSerg In `CoreDoCommandCoreStateSet` I change `IntPtr` to `ref int`. https://pastebin.com/cz8QnsaY

Comment: @GSerg Using `int` instead of `ref int` causes nothing to happen, and no problems with the program.

Comment: That looks correct, and certainly should not cause memory access issues, unless the pointer is supposed to be remembered by the API for later use. If that is the case, allocate an array of one int, pin it, pass the pointer and do not unpin until a condition occurs what makes the API forget the passed pointer. Another option is that in this case a raw value is expected, in which case leave the parameter as `IntPtr` and pass `new IntPtr(0)` or `new IntPtr(1)`.

Comment: @GSerg Can you modify my pastebin code and show how to allocate the array and pin it correctly? For the other suggestion, using `new IntPtr(0)` caused nothing to happen. Using `new IntPtr(1)` gave the error `System.AccessViolationException ("Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an idication that other memory is corrupt.")`.

Comment: So an actual pointer is expected, and the API ignores the null pointer. Declare a global `int` variable somewhere that would live for entire duration of the program and pass that as `ref int`.

Comment: @GSerg I made a `public int mute = 0;`. When run, `0` made the program's window go black, and `1` made the window height shrink to just the title bar left. And also didn't mute the program. What's odd is that I've called other API commands without problem, but they've all used `IntPtr.Zero`, which isn't used in this case.

Comment: Also, what is the [size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8115895/11683) of the `m64p_command` and `m64p_core_param` enums on the C++ side?

Comment: Do you have the `m64p_core_param` enum properly declared? Make sure each entry is explicitly assigned with the value it has on the C++ side (`M64CMD_NOP = 0, M64CMD_ROM_OPEN = 1` etc).

Comment: @GSerg I'm not sure, I will check if I have them properly declared. I think this is the Mupen64Plus core source file with the enums https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core/blob/master/src/api/m64p_types.h

Comment: @GSerg I compared my `enum m64p_core_param` list with that source file and there was a missing `M64CORE_EMU_STATE = 1` value. When I set that and ran a test, it successfully muted. Thanks for your help, if you want to write an answer I'll accept.

Comment: @GSerg I have a new question about using a `struct` with this API, if you'd like to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57603448/6806643