# Populate C# struct using Mupen64Plus Unmanaged C dll API command

Tags: c#, c, struct, dll, unmanaged

I'm using [Mupen64Plus](https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core) and the included `m64p_test_rom.v64` file.

I'm using **C#** to talk to the `mupen64plus.dll` API which is written in **C**.

---

**Problem**

I'm trying to use its API command `M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER` to get the ROM Header from `m64p_test_rom.v64`, which contains properties like `Name`, `Manufacturer ID`, `Country code`. It looks like the command stores the data in a `struct`.

The problem is that when the API command is called to populate the `struct`, the variables remain null, it does not populate it with new values.

---

### API

I'm using this C# [API code](https://github.com/TASVideos/BizHawk/blob/master/BizHawk.Emulation.Cores/Consoles/Nintendo/N64/NativeApi/mupen64plusCoreApi.cs) from BizHawk to talk to `mupen64plus.dll`.

**Commands**

[Mupen64Plus v2.0 Core Front-End Wiki](https://mupen64plus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Mupen64Plus_v2.0_Core_Front-End)

1. **CoreDoCommand(m64p_command Command, int ParamInt, void *ParamPtr)**

   Command Enumerated type specifying which command should be executed.

   ParamInt: An integer value which may be used as an input to the command.
   ParamPtr: A pointer which may be used as an input to the command.
2. **M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER**

   This will retrieve the header data of the currently open ROM. A ROM image must be open.

   ParamInt: Pointer to a rom_header struct *to receive the data*.
   ParamPtr: The size in bytes of the rom_header struct.

---

### ROM Header struct

In my `C#` project I created a new `struct` to match the one in the Mupen64Plus's `C` source code. I'm not sure if I have converted it from `C` to `C#` correctly.

**Mupen64Plus C** [m64p_types.h](https://github.com/mupen64plus/mupen64plus-core/blob/master/src/api/m64p_types.h)

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t  init_PI_BSB_DOM1_LAT_REG;  /* 0x00 */
   uint8_t  init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PGS_REG;  /* 0x01 */
   uint8_t  init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PWD_REG;  /* 0x02 */
   uint8_t  init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PGS_REG2; /* 0x03 */
   uint32_t ClockRate;                 /* 0x04 */
   uint32_t PC;                        /* 0x08 */
   uint32_t Release;                   /* 0x0C */
   uint32_t CRC1;                      /* 0x10 */
   uint32_t CRC2;                      /* 0x14 */
   uint32_t Unknown[2];                /* 0x18 */
   uint8_t  Name[20];                  /* 0x20 */
   uint32_t unknown;                   /* 0x34 */
   uint32_t Manufacturer_ID;           /* 0x38 */
   uint16_t Cartridge_ID;              /* 0x3C - Game serial number  */
   uint16_t Country_code;              /* 0x3E */
} m64p_rom_header;
```

**My C# struct**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct m64p_rom_header
{
    public byte init_PI_BSB_DOM1_LAT_REG;  /* 0x00 */
    public byte init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PGS_REG;  /* 0x01 */
    public byte init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PWD_REG;  /* 0x02 */
    public byte init_PI_BSB_DOM1_PGS_REG2; /* 0x03 */
    public uint ClockRate;                 /* 0x04 */
    public uint PC;                        /* 0x08 */
    public uint Release;                   /* 0x0C */
    public uint CRC1;                      /* 0x10 */
    public uint CRC2;                      /* 0x14 */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public uint[] Unknown;                 /* 0x18 */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public byte[] Name;                    /* 0x20 */
    public uint unknown;                   /* 0x34 */
    public uint Manufacturer_ID;           /* 0x38 */
    public ushort Cartridge_ID;            /* 0x3C - Game serial number  */
    public ushort Country_code;            /* 0x3E */
};
```

---

### Unmanaged Function Pointer

I've added a new delegate declaration so I can use the API's `CoreDoCommand()` function and `M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER` command.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate m64p_error CoreDoCommandStruct(m64p_command Command, m64p_rom_header ParamInt, ref int ParamPtr);
CoreDoCommandStruct m64pCoreDoCommandStruct;
```

---

#### ROM Get Header

I'm trying to retrieve the ROM's Name.

Running the API command `M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER` should populate the `m64p_rom_header` `struct`.

The `Name` poperty should return as `Mupen64Plus Demo by Marshallh (GPL)`.

I get the error `ArgumentNullException: Array cannot be null.` on `rom_header.Name`.

The ROM is open and running when i call the command.

---

```
public m64p_rom_header rom_header;

public String ROMGetHeader()
{
    // Get size of ROM Header struct
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(m64p_rom_header)); // returns value of 20?

    // API ROM Get Header Command
    // Question: Populates all variables in the m64p_rom_header struct?
    m64pCoreDoCommandStruct(m64p_command.M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER, rom_header, ref size);

    // Return the byte Array and convert to String
    return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(rom_header.Name); // <-- Error: Array null
}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks, I have not yet tried the question wizard. I tried to make the question less complicated by laying out all the info so it's easier to read and understand the API. As it's taken me about 3 days to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined/passed the parameters to the method in the wrong order. The second parameter of the delegate is of type **int** and the third parameter is a **void pointer** in **C** and should be used to pass data as a reference.
For example, you can find the following code in the link you sent (BizHawk/mupen64pluseCoreApi.cs) :

```
// Pass the rom to the core
result = m64pCoreDoCommandByteArray(m64p_command.M64CMD_ROM_OPEN, rom.Length, rom);
```

So the definition of the delegate should be as the following:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate m64p_error CoreDoCommandStruct(m64p_command Command, int ParamInt, ref m64p_rom_header ParamPtr);
CoreDoCommandStruct m64pCoreDoCommandStruct;
```

and the way you use it should be as the following:

```
m64pCoreDoCommandStruct(m64p_command.M64CMD_ROM_GET_HEADER, size, ref rom_header);
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that mistake, that solved the problem and displays the name now.